# Force beamer to look in the CWD for theme?

Tags: beamer, themes

I have a multiple-author document that I want to use a custom theme for. The document is stored in git, and I would like to store the theme file in the same directory (or a sub-directory), so that it we can keep track of them.

The theme file is called `beamerthemeTHEMENAME.sty`. I've tried storing it in the same directory, and including it with

```
\usetheme{THEMENAME}
```

But beamer refuses to find it. This is really annoying, because when I compile with my document `latexmk -pdf ...` I can *manually* change the theme name to `./beamerthemeTHEMENAME.sty` during compilation, and it works fine, but beamer just doesn't look in the local directory.

Is there any way to force beamer to look for theme files in the current working directory, or a subdirectory of it?

Comment: I copied `beamerthemeMadrid.sty` to `beamerthemeMyMadrid.sty`, changed the `\ProvidesPackage` line to reflect the new name and `\usetheme{MyMadrid}` found the file in the current directory.

Comment: @egreg: that works for me too, if I change the directory in the `\ProvidesPackageRCS $Header:` to `./beamerthemeTHEMENAME.sty`. Put that in an answer, and I'll accept it. It'd be good if someone could provide an explanation of the `\ProvidesPackageRCS` command, since google returns 0 results for it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that the local theme wasn't read in. Probably you got a spurious warning about the name.

Change the `\ProvidesPackageRCS` line into

```
\ProvidesPackage{beamerthemeTHEMENAME}
```